# Solving circle's radius only knowing angle & lengths of external triangle OR solving for sides of a triangle partial side lengths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, circles, triangles

Is this possible?

Given that I know the length of Y and Z and the angle of X can I figure out the radius A?

If I can't without more information, I can produce another set of data X Y Z at a different angle x with an identical radius A.

How can I solve for radius A?  And is there a method to solve side B without knowing radius A?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, indeed we have
$$ (y+a)=(z+a)\cdot \cos(x) \iff a = \frac{y+z\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)} $$

Comment: Awesome thank you!  Is there a simplified method to solve for b without calculating a?

Comment: Doh, You have to know a side to figure out other sides, thanks my brain.  And thanks again for the answer abramo

Comment: Does this work for acute or obtuse triangle’s?